# Discrete math counting principles

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> In how many ways can a teacher distribute 12 identical science books among 15 students if
>
> 1) no student gets more than one book?
>
> 2) if the oldest student gets two books but no other student gets more than one book?

Initially, I tried the binomial theorems with the idea that the student gets a book or no book but that is not giving me the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the students are distinguishable:

For the first one: If no student gets more than one book, then it is just a matter of finding the number of ways to pick 12 students out of those 15, i.e. $15 \choose 12$

For the second one: the oldest one gets 2 books ... leaving 14 students ... and 10 books ... can you do the rest?

Comment: This is an exam prep so I don't have the actual answers, so I just want to make sure I am correct in my thinking.

So the first is 15c12 = 455 

and the second is 14c10 =1001

Comment: @critter1854 Yes, correct!

Comment: @N.F.Taussig But the books are identical ...

Answer (score 1):

Hint for 1) Count the number of subsets of  cardinality $12$ of a set of $15$ elements.

Hint for 2) Count the number of subsets of  cardinality $12-2$ of a set of $15-1$ elements.

Comment: The books are identical!